# My code not works in search functionality

Tags: android

My code gives the phone contact details that is phone number and contact name.I used the below code but its not work properly in search functionality.give me more suggestions for that. I am getting the error at line servers_adp.getFilter().filter(text); here it shows the create method error for getFilter()

```
package com.syphersafe.securefiles;
public class ContactsActivity extends BaseActivity{
EditText searchcontact_et;
ArrayList<String> namearr,numarr,photoarr;
ArrayAdapter<String> adp;
ServerAdapter servers_adp;
ListView lstContacts;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    searchcontact_et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSeachcontact);
    servers_adp = new ServerAdapter();
    namearr =   new ArrayList<String>();
    numarr      =   new ArrayList<String>();
    photoarr   =  new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);
      searchcontact_et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
private boolean mCountIncreased;
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)  {}
@Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int    count,int after) {}
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  String text =     searchcontact_et.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                servers_adp.getFilter().filter(text);
            }
        });
}

 protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Cursor cursornum = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursornum != null) {
        while (cursornum.moveToNext()) {
            String contactname  =    cursornum.getString(cursornum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactnum   =    cursornum.getString(cursornum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            namearr.add(contactname);
            numarr.add(contactnum);
            //photoarr.add(photoPath);
        }
    }lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);
     lstContacts.setAdapter(servers_adp);super.onStart();
}
public class ServerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return namearr.size();
}
public Object getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                //no constraint given, just return all the data. (no search)
                results.count = list.size();
                results.values = list;
            } else {//do the search
                List<String> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                String searchStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                for (String s : list)
                    if (s.toUpperCase().contains(searchStr)) resultsData.add(s);
                results.count = resultsData.size();
                results.values = resultsData;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            listFiltered = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_layout, null);
    TextView contact_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
    ImageView contact_photo = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.contact_photo);
    TextView contact_num=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
    try {
        String arlstname[] = namearr.get(position).split(",");
        String arlstnumber[] = numarr.get(position).split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < arlstname.length; i++) {
            contact_name.setText(arlstname[i]);
            contact_num.setText(arlstnumber[i]);
            if(arlstname[i].equals("Lav")|| arlstname[i].equals("Teja")){
                Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.call_person);
                contact_photo.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
                 }
            else{
                Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                contact_photo.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
              }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return v;
}
}   
}
```

Comment: Please show your filter Class so we can debug.

Comment: I post my entire code for that functionality please suggest the correct solution for filtring

Answer (score 0):

First make your Adapter implement Filterable. You will get error to add methods. Add the method

```
    public Filter getFilter() {
     }
```

And inside that method copy paste all the code inside public Object getFilter() method. Once you have done that remove the public Object getFilter() method.

It should work.

```
    public class ContactsActivity extends BaseActivity{
EditText searchcontact_et;
ArrayList<String> namearr,numarr,photoarr;
ArrayAdapter<String> adp;
ServerAdapter servers_adp;
ListView lstContacts;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    searchcontact_et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSeachcontact);
    servers_adp = new ServerAdapter();
    namearr =   new ArrayList<String>();
    numarr      =   new ArrayList<String>();
    photoarr   =  new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);
    searchcontact_et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private boolean mCountIncreased;
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)  {}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int    count,int after) {}
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text =     searchcontact_et.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            servers_adp.getFilter().filter(text);
        }
    });
}

protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Cursor cursornum = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursornum != null) {
        while (cursornum.moveToNext()) {
            String contactname  =    cursornum.getString(cursornum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactnum   =    cursornum.getString(cursornum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            namearr.add(contactname);
            numarr.add(contactnum);
            //photoarr.add(photoPath);
        }
    }lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);
    lstContacts.setAdapter(servers_adp);super.onStart();
}
public class ServerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return namearr.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_layout, null);
        TextView contact_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        ImageView contact_photo = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.contact_photo);
        TextView contact_num=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
        try {
            String arlstname[] = namearr.get(position).split(",");
            String arlstnumber[] = numarr.get(position).split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < arlstname.length; i++) {
                contact_name.setText(arlstname[i]);
                contact_num.setText(arlstnumber[i]);
                if(arlstname[i].equals("Lav")|| arlstname[i].equals("Teja")){
                    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.call_person);
                    contact_photo.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
                }
                else{
                    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    contact_photo.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    //no constraint given, just return all the data. (no search)
                    results.count = list.size();
                    results.values = list;
                } else {//do the search
                    List<String> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                    for (String s : list)
                        if (s.toUpperCase().contains(searchStr)) resultsData.add(s);
                    results.count = resultsData.size();
                    results.values = resultsData;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                listFiltered = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am adding the implement Filterable but Inside the filter class shows errors.please share the corresponding code for that

Comment: Cast error for the "return new Filter(){}; for this

Comment: In import packages it shows  "the type android.widget.Filter.FilterResults is not visible"